# Simplify by combining indicies.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am new to this site.

I am trying to simplify this expression by combining indices.

$(E^4 \cdot E^7 \cdot E^{-2.6} \cdot E^{-1})^3$

I think it should be: $E^{4 + 7 - 2.6 - 1}$ without the ^3

But I am not to sure what to do with the ^3. I know it means to times. But not sure what to times, or how. Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Luke

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! It is not clear what you are trying to ask. Try to improve your question by adding some context and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for writing math here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in saying that when the variables are multiplied you add the exponents together,

$$ E^4 \cdot E^7 \cdot E^{-2.6} \cdot E^{-1} = E^{4+7-2.6-1} = E^{7.4} $$

Now you multiply the $7.4$ by the outer exponent three, because $ (x^a)^b = x^{a\cdot b}$, so

$$ (E^{7.4})^3 = E^{7.4\cdot 3} = E^{22.2} $$

You can see some properties of exponents [here](https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-1/exponents-and-exponential-functions/properties-of-exponents).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$E^7 \cdot E^4 \cdot E^{-2.6} \cdot E^{-1} = E^{7.4}$

And

$(E^{7.4})^3 = E^{22.2}$

Thus, power on same variable adds when they are multiplied.

So,

$(a^2)^x = \underbrace{a^2 \cdot a^2 \cdot....}_x = a^{\overbrace{2 + 2 +....}^x} = a ^{2x}$

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated